# R create column in new data frame if cells values match in two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame 'DF1' with two columns that might have repeat data like such:

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-13 | Bob |
| 2022-03-13 | Bob |
| 2022-03-13 | Tim |
| 2022-03-14 | Bob |
| 2022-03-13 | Tim |
| 2022-03-14 | Jim |

I want to create a new data frame 'DF2' that populates a new column called 'Count' that counts those repeats with the prefix 'Count'. The new data frame should also include the Date and Name information from the original column so that the new data frame looks like this:

| Date | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-13 | Bob | Count 2 |
| 2022-03-13 | Tim | Count 2 |
| 2022-03-14 | Bob | Count 1 |
| 2022-03-14 | Jim | Count 1 |

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need `count` or `table` i.e `dplyr::count(df1, Date, Name, name = 'Count')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the prefix "Count" you can use the `paste()` function, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "Date   Name
2022-03-13  Bob
2022-03-13  Bob
2022-03-13  Tim
2022-03-14  Bob
2022-03-13  Tim
2022-03-14  Jim", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(Name, Date) %>%
  summarise(Count = paste("Count", n(), sep = " ")) %>%
  arrange(desc(Count))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   Name [3]
#>   Name  Date       Count  
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>  
#> 1 Bob   2022-03-13 Count 2
#> 2 Tim   2022-03-13 Count 2
#> 3 Bob   2022-03-14 Count 1
#> 4 Jim   2022-03-14 Count 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This works great and adds the prefix. Thank you! Can you let me know which part of the code names the new column 'Count' and how I could change the name of that column?

Comment: The column name comes from the `summarise(Count =` part ("Count" can be changed to anything)